# access_token expires? I'm trying to query a public post w/JS. Easier way?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Beginner here, and I've been getting lost in the Facebook developer docs and Google for hours. I'm sure this is a simple question, but I just need some direction.

What I'm trying to do: query latest post of a page owner from a public Facebook page with JavaScript and parse it to display within my own HTML (can't use a [Social Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) - I need custom control over HTML/CSS).

What I've got working so far:

```
var token = '<my_token>';
var query = 'fields=posts.limit(1)';
var request = 'https://graph.facebook.com/[mypage]?' + query + '&access_token=' + token;
$.getJSON(request, function(response) {
  alert(response.posts.data[0].message);
});
```

This does work, however, the [Access Token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=) says my access_token is going to expire in 2 months. Why? It's a public Facebook page, and I only want to query the page owner's latest comment. Do I really need to create a Facebook App and login via PHP to just to access this public information?

I'm doing the exact same thing with a Twitter feed and all I had to do was $.getJSON http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/.json, completely in JavaScript.

It seems getting similar information from Facebook is much more difficult, but perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

> This does work, however, the Access Token debugger says my access_token is going to expire in 2 months. Why?

Because that’s what user access tokens do.

> Do I really need to create a Facebook App and login via PHP to just to access this public information?

For pages that are restricted in any way (based on age, country or for alcohol related content) you *have* to use a user access token, because that’s the only way Facebook can figure out whether you’re actually allowed to see the content or not.

If it’s your own page, then you could generate a page access token – those don’t expire by default, if you use a long-lived user access token to get them.

But you don’t want to expose that kind of token in client-side JavaScript, because everyone visiting your site could steal it from there and act on behalf of your page then.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I'm having difficulty finding an example that doesn't require a client-initiated login. (Obviously, the client doesn't care to login just to see a feed.) Any resources? I'm all over the Facebook docs...